# experiment with ARP (NETWORK lab)

Tags: linux, networking

I wanted to know if we ping the loopback interface by typing "ping localhost" at console prompt,could any ICMP packet be obeserved on the output of my TCPDUMP? and why?

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is making sure you specify the correct interface, in this case lo

```
root@generic:~# tcpdump -n -i lo
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
20:00:37.260209 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 27850, seq 1, length 64
20:00:37.260228 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27850, seq 1, length 64
20:00:38.260590 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 27850, seq 2, length 64
20:00:38.260611 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27850, seq 2, length 64
20:00:39.260587 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 27850, seq 3, length 64
20:00:39.260609 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27850, seq 3, length 64
20:00:40.260620 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 27850, seq 4, length 64
20:00:40.260643 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27850, seq 4, length 64
^C
8 packets captured
16 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Might be useful to explain why, so people can reference this in future and learn something!